# hibernate to update email as proper email with the firstname from database?

Tags: hibernate

I want to update the email in my database as the proper email for example abc.@gmial.com  in order to do this I want read the firstName from the database but when I write the below syntax it gives me error

my syntax is using hibernate session.createQuery.

```
Student myStudent=new Student();
                 
session.createQuery("update Student set email="+myStudent.getFirstName()+"'@gmail.com'").executeUpdate();
```

the error is
ERROR: line 1:65: unexpected token: '@gmail.com'
line 1:65: unexpected token: '@gmail.com'
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.concatenation(HqlBaseParser.java:760)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.newValue(HqlBaseParser.java:615)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.assignment(HqlBaseParser.java:569)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.setClause(HqlBaseParser.java:498)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.updateStatement(HqlBaseParser.java:248)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.statement(HqlBaseParser.java:183)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.parse(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:294)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:189)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:144)
at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.(HQLQueryPlan.java:113)
at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.(HQLQueryPlan.java:73)
at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:162)
at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.getQueryPlan(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:604)
at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:716)
at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:113)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.hibernate.context.internal.ThreadLocalSessionContext$TransactionProtectionWrapper.invoke(ThreadLocalSessionContext.java:351)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy30.createQuery(Unknown Source)
at com.luv2code.hibernate.demo.UpdateStudentDemo.main(UpdateStudentDemo.java:53)

Jan 12, 2021 8:00:32 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl$PoolState stop
INFO: HHH10001008: Cleaning up connection pool [jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hb_student_tracker?useSSL=false]
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: '@gmail.com' near line 1, column 65 [update com.luv2code.hibernate.demo.entity.Student set email=null'@gmail.com']
at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:138)
at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:181)
at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:188)
at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:725)
at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:113)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.hibernate.context.internal.ThreadLocalSessionContext$TransactionProtectionWrapper.invoke(ThreadLocalSessionContext.java:351)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy30.createQuery(Unknown Source)
at com.luv2code.hibernate.demo.UpdateStudentDemo.main(UpdateStudentDemo.java:53)
Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: '@gmail.com' near line 1, column 65 [update com.luv2code.hibernate.demo.entity.Student set email=null'@gmail.com']
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException.convert(QuerySyntaxException.java:74)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ErrorTracker.throwQueryException(ErrorTracker.java:93)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.parse(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:301)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:189)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:144)
at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.(HQLQueryPlan.java:113)
at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.(HQLQueryPlan.java:73)
at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:162)
at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.getQueryPlan(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:604)
at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:716)
... 8 more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HQL is similar to SQL. If you want to update the emails of all students, then use something like this:

```
session.createQuery("update Student set email = concat(firstName,'@gmail.com')").executeUpdate();
```